# как построить запрос SQL получить компании у которых user имеет имя Jon и этих Jon больше 2?

Tags: sql

```
вот так не хочет
SELECT DISTINCT
    companies.name
FROM
    companies 
INNER JOIN users
ON companies.id = users.company_id
WHERE users.name = 'Jon'
#AND COUNT(users) > 1 этот код вызывает ошибку
```

Comment: GROUP BY + HAVING

Comment: можете показать куда его писать?

Comment: спасибо нашел
SELECT DISTINCT
    companies.name
FROM
    companies INNER JOIN users
ON companies.id = users.company_id
WHERE users.name = 'Jon'
HAVING COUNT(users.id) > 2

Comment: вы пропустили ```group by```

Comment: group by по какому полю?

Comment: *спасибо нашел* Запрос синтаксически некорректен. Но даже если выполнится в какой-то СУБД, даст неверный результат.

Comment: ну как построить корректный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно выбрать только название компании, то можно построить подзапрос с требуемыми условиями:

```sql
SELECT companyName 
FROM (
    SELECT c.name companyName, COUNT(*) userCount
    FROM companies c
    INNER JOIN users u ON c.id = u.company_id
    WHERE u.name = 'Jon'
    GROUP BY c.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) t
```